# Love in islam is Haram or halal?

Tags: love

Hi my name is Mubashir Ahmed.Im a Muslim.
I want to ask about love in Islam.I love my cousin for almost 4 years .I never told her about my attraction towards her as i considered it to be a really bad act, if someone came to know about my proposal then they probably considered me as a jerk . Another reason is that she is so innocent and i don't anyone to point towards her. Another reason that i didn't told her about my attraction towards her is that her brother is my really great fellow and if sometimes i think about telling her about my attraction towards her ,i consider myself as her brother and think that if my best fellow send proposal to my sister so how would i react?.
I thing more my attraction is not any sort of sexual attraction its just like having crush on someone and nothing else. I just wanted to marry her.

Answer (score 2):

Love is like any other feeling or desire, e.g. huger or thirst, which is in our nature and can't be controlled. It can't be Haram unless you fulfill it in a Haram way.
So, if fall in love with someone, try to fulfill it in a Halal way: Marriage, not Haram way: Zinah

Answer (score 1):

**Love in Islam is halal** if you don't hurt someone else and if your intention is to marry her there is no problem with that but if your intention only to do zina or lust  this is different ,you should hide this intention from any one, if you can't wait to marry her **you should marry her otherwise leave her alone, don't tell her about your feeling or anyone else who can abuse her**

> حدثنا محمد أخبرنا عبد الوهاب حدثنا خالد عن عكرمة عن ابن عباس أن زوج
>   بريرة كان عبدا يقال له مغيث كأني أنظر إليه يطوف خلفها يبكي ودموعه تسيل
>   على لحيته فقال النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم لعباس يا عباس ألا تعجب من حب
>   مغيث بريرة ومن بغض بريرة مغيثا فقال النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم لو راجعته
>   قالت يا رسول الله تأمرني قال إنما أنا أشفع قالت لا حاجة لي فيه
>   بريرة ([Source](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/68/32))

The story of a fair story that she wanted to be freed from slavery slavery, and to start in the horizons of freedom, own itself, and to take its decision, and the full capacity to determine their destiny, and chart their future. 
aftershe become free
When she thought that she was the wife of Abdul Mamlouk, Islam gives her the freedom to make a decision, she has to keep her marital relationship as it is, the same as before, and can break the bond, and resolve the bond, decided decisively and resolutely to end her marriage. And so it was, because she did not love her husband, nor bear in her heart his affection and no mercy.

and the prophet(صلى الله عليه وسلم) sow that and he was wondering about the love of the man and the hate of the women

> يقول ابن عباس رضي الله عنهما : إن زوج بريرة كان عبدا يقال له مغيث ، كأني أنظر إليه يطوف خلفها يبكي ودموعه تسيل على لحيته فقال النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم لعباس : يا عباس ، ألا تعجب من حب مغيث بريرة ومن بغض بريرة مغيثا ؟ رواه البخاري

her ex husband  asked the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allah be upon him):
to be mediator then Prophet (صلى الله عليه وسلم) told her if she return to him she said do you order me he said I'm mediator she said I don't need him

**The conclusion if Love was Haram Prophet Muhammad will not be mediator**